# Компилятор C# на Ubuntu/Debian

Tags: c#, linux

Вопрос может примитивен. Но есть какой-то компилятор C# под серверный Ubuntu/Debian, чтобы можно запускать файл из консоли. Просто то, что искал в интернете -> приводило к Visual Studio Code, но нужно именно в консоли.

Comment: Посмотрите, что такое .NET Core. Именно Core, а не Framework. Он вроде кроссплатформенный

Comment: Вам нужно установить на машину .NET Core SDK. Visual Studio Code - это лишь редактор кода

Comment: [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Code это просто редактор кода. Не совсем даже IDE. Вам нужен [.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/linux), microsoft даже открыла [его исходники](https://github.com/dotnet/core).

Репозитории [тут](https://packages.microsoft.com/), ключ [тут](https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc), инструкция по установке в 18.04 [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#1804-)

Для VSCode вам будут полезны [вот эти плагины](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=doggy8088.netcore-extension-pack)